# Eulers Integral Formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

In his famous works on complex analysis Euler proved these integrals for $n=1$ $$\frac{\Gamma (s)}{n|p|^s}\cos{(\alpha s)}=\int_0^{\infty}u^{ns-1}\exp{(-\text{Re}(p)u^n)}\cos{(\text{Im}(p)u^n)}du$$

$$\frac{\Gamma (s)}{n|p|^s}\sin{(\alpha s)}=\int_0^{\infty}u^{ns-1}\exp{(-\text{Re}(p)u^n)}\sin{(\text{Im}(p)u^n)}du$$

He derived them in "Zur Theorie komplexer Funktionen" (1768-1783; here is a video that is showing a [non-rigorous derivation based on Euler's derivation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF7ud3Al6d8)).

Using these formulas, one can derive following integrals as a special case

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\int_0^{\infty}\sin{(u^2)}du=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}$$

$$\int_0^{\infty}\cos{(u^2)}du=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}$$

My question is, are there even more general formulas of this type e.g. having polynomials in $u$ instead of just powers of $u$? Or independent polynomials for the exponential and the trigonometric argument, eg. $g(u)$ in the exponential and $h(u)$ in the trigonometric functions.