# Calculating improper complex integral $\int_0^{+\infty}(x^2+2x)\exp(\omega x)\sin(x) \mathrm{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^{+\infty}(x^2+2x)\exp(\omega x)\sin(x) \mathrm{dx}$$

$$\omega \in \mathbb{C}, \mathrm{Re}(\omega)<0$$

How do I solve this - what's the best way to calculate this integral? Looking at real part and imaginary part separately?

Comment: This is the Laplace transform of $(x^2+2x)\sin(x)$ evaluated at $s=-\omega$.

Comment: Unfortunately we didn't hear about this yet in lecture

Answer (score 1):

First, let's rename the variable $\omega =-s$ such that we obtain

$$\int_0^{+\infty}(x^2+2x)\exp(-s x)\sin(x) \mathrm{dx}.$$

Then use $s=a+jb$ and Euler's formula as a substitution to obtain

$$\int_0^{+\infty}(x^2+2x)\exp(-a x-jbx)\sin(x) \mathrm{dx}=\int_0^{+\infty}(x^2+2x)\exp(-a x)\exp(-jbx)\sin(x) \mathrm{dx}$$
$$=\int_0^{+\infty}(x^2+2x)\exp(-a x)\left[\cos(bx)-j\sin(bx)\right]\sin(x) \mathrm{dx}$$
$$=\int_0^{+\infty}(x^2+2x)\exp(-a x)\cos(bx)\sin(x) \mathrm{dx}$$
$$-j\int_0^{+\infty}(x^2+2x)\exp(-a x)\sin(bx)\sin(x) \mathrm{dx}.$$

In the next step apply

$$\sin u \cos v= \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\sin(u-v)+\sin(u+v) \right]$$
$$\sin u \sin v= \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\cos(u-v)+\cos(u+v) \right]$$

to turn the products of trigonometric functions into sums of trigonometric functions.

Then apply [Euler's integral formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437786/eulers-integral-formula) to obtain the solutions to the appearing integrals.

Comment: Thanks! But which of those formulas do you mean - i dont really see the connection?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{x^{2} + 2x}
\exp\pars{\omega x}\sin\pars{x}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{\omega}\ <\ 0}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{\partiald[2]{}{\omega} + 2\,\partiald{}{\omega}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{\omega x}\,{\expo{\ic x} - \expo{-\ic x} \over 2\ic}\,\dd x =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ic\pars{\partiald[2]{}{\omega} + 2\,\partiald{}{\omega}}
\pars{{-1 \over \omega + \ic} - {-1 \over \omega - \ic}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ic\pars{\partiald{}{\omega} + 2}
\bracks{{1 \over \pars{\omega + \ic}^{2}} - {1 \over \pars{\omega - \ic}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ic
\bracks{-\,{2 \over \pars{\omega + \ic}^{3}} +
{2 \over \pars{\omega - \ic}^{3}} + {2 \over \pars{\omega + \ic}^{2}} -
{2 \over \pars{\omega - \ic}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{\ic \over \pars{\omega + \ic}^{3}} -
{\ic \over \pars{\omega - \ic}^{3}} - {\ic \over \pars{\omega + \ic}^{2}} +
{\ic \over \pars{\omega - \ic}^{2}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, that is a great technique. It reduces a lot of the calculations.

Comment: @MrYouMath It's always useful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @FelixMarin i don' fully understand it yet. Can you explain step by step what you did? In the first step, you wrote $\sin(x)$ in a other way but what did you do before the $\int$-symbol? And then in the next steps, what is happening there? The last step is understandable.

Comment: @joha1412 Note that $\left(x^{2} + 2x\right)\exp\left(\omega x\right) =
{\displaystyle{\partial^{2}\exp\left(\omega x\right) \over \partial\omega^{2}} + 2{\partial\exp\left(\omega x\right) \over \partial\omega}}$. It left us with   integrals like $\int\exp\left(\left[\omega \pm \mathrm{i}\right]x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = {\displaystyle{ \exp\left(\left[\omega \pm \mathrm{i}\right]x\right) \over \omega \pm \mathrm{i}}}$. That was the main reason to use this approach.